# Binding async functions in constructor

Tags: babeljs

I am trying to bind an async function with babel, without using property initalizers. (I am doing a test). The reason I need to bind is because they are added to `onClick`, which makes them lose the `this`.

It works fine with `editEntry` below, as that is not async. But when I try with `deleteEntry` it causes the error:

> TypeError: _this.saveEntry is undefined

This is my class:

```
class RowActions extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.warn('binding functions');
        this.editEntry = this.editEntry.bind(this);
        this.saveEntry = this.saveEntry.bind(this);
        console.warn('binding functions done');
    }
    editEntry(e) {
        let { blah } = this.props;
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    async saveEdit(e) {
        let { blah } = this.props;
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    render() {
        let { blah } = this.props;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.saveEntry` is undefined, because there is no method with that name,  you only have `saveEdit`. You probably meant:

```
this.saveEdit = this.saveEdit.bind(this);
```